# How can I extract ions from a dielectric barrier discharge plasma and then measure them?

Tags: plasma-physics

I would like to pull the ions out of a DBD plasma, what is the best way to do this? Then the ion current is to be measured. What basically happens when I pull ions out of the DBD plasma (recombination etc.)? Can I use an electrode to pull the ions out of the plasma and thus also measure the ion current? How far away would this electrode need to be and what voltage magnitudes would I need to apply for this?
Maybe someone has some ideas.

Comment: The high operating pressure raises some engineering issues, but otherwise you extract them in pretty much the same way you would extract from any ion source.